# Jquery and AJAX sending only the first row of values

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, grails, controller

I met with some problem regarding JQUERY and AJAX. I shall post my codes first,

AJAX:

```
 $('#edittable').live('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            success: function(html){

                $("#edit1").html(html).dialog("open")

             });
            },

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<form id="edittable">
    <div style="height: 250px; overflow: scroll; width: 100%;">
        <table id="normal">
            <g:each in="${result}">
                <tr id="btn">
                    <td width=10%>
                        ${it.ID}
                    </td>
                    <td width=25%>
                        <span id="user">
                            ${it.username}
                        </span>
                        <input type="hidden" name="editusers" id="editusers"
                                value="${it.username}" readonly>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </g:each>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do here is, to retrieve the hidden input from the table form (edittable) and send it back to my controller. It is doable and my controller retrieves it. However, it only receives the first row values, even if I click on other rows, it still receives the first row values. Anyone has any idea what should I do to fix this problem? Thanks guys.

Comment: because you have only one row in the table? if you want to send the multiple rows you will have to receive `List` at the controller end

Comment: No, I have multiple rows in the table. And it only retrieves the first row even though I clicked on the 2nd or 3rd row. How do you do that?

Comment: You need to give each input a different name so the controller can tell them apart.

Comment: debug the `params` object (in the controller) and check what you receive in the request

Comment: @aldrin Like i said, its only receiving the first row values. I did a println and the result their giving is from the first row.

Comment: @Barmar Its ${it.?}, the result is being iterated, how do I set different id for that <td>?

Comment: i'm seeing javascript errors in your ajax code. can you check your javascript console for any errors?

Comment: Erm, nope... It's running smoothly..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know grails, so I'm just guessing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="editusers${it.ID}" value="{it.username}" readonly>`
```

You also need to make the other IDs in the table unique. Probably you don't need IDs in the `<tr>` and `<span>` elements in the first place.

Comment: Hi barmar, thanks for replying. So what do I put in the controller? in my controller i put : request.getParameter("editusers") . So, how do i retrieve the numbers from the ${it.ID}??

Comment: Like I said, I don't know grails. If I were doing this in PHP, I'd use `name='editusers[]'`, which makes it an array. Maybe grails has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Barmer answer
Change for g:each to include an index

```
    <g:each status="i" in="${result}">
```

Make the index part of parameter name

```
    <input type="hidden" name="editusers[${i}]" value="${it.username}" readonly>
```

You should be able to values as list in from params

```
    params.editusers
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, I have a validation check and it points to a specific id in the input type, so how does the validation iterate the names?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this to form data post
<script type="text/javascript">
var form_data = $('#edittable').serializeArray();
 $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            data: {post:form_data},
            type: "POST",
            success: function(html){

                $("#edit1").html(html).dialog("open")

             });
            }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your codes. But it isn't sending any data back to the controller.

Comment: plz try to print print_r($_POST), so u can see which variable is posted in controller...

Comment: I'm using grails and gsp(HTML). Not using php.

Answer (score 0):

Use append instead of html in success function

```
$("#edit1").append(html).dialog("open")
```

Comment: Hi Jamir, thanks for answering. But it is not work, it gave me the values from the last row of the table. Additionally, it keeps on adding more fields whenever i cancel and click it again.